# OpenTok Web SDK on iOs: session.publish reloads page

Tags: ios, ionic2, publish, opentok

I have set up a video-call app using the Vonage Video API and Ionic. I am using the web SDK. Everything works perfectly on browser and android devices, but I have one problem on iOs devices: after creating a publisher and calling session.publish, my app reloads instantly. The callback from session.publish does not get called, the reload happens before that. All I see is a pending "ClientEvent" XHR call that never gets resolved.

Before you ask, the user has camera and microphone permissions.

Comment: Which version of iOS is this on?

Comment: Hi @abdujalet thanks for answering. This is on iOs 15.1.

Comment: Mind hopping onto our slack so I can take a closer look at things? We have a #video-api channel https://developer.vonage.com/community/slack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using the VP8 video codec instead of the H264 one. It's an ongoing issue in iOs 15.1.

Comment: For anyone who runs across this issue, you can change the codec setting in your project from the tokbox dashboard.